# How to identify application that calls web service

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I have a Java servlet application with 6 web services and one of the web requests I must determine if it is the Live or Test instance calling the web service.  I believe I can determine this from URL, i.e.

```
 https://localhost:8443/projectname/etc
```

or

```
https://localhost:8443/projectnameTEST/etc
```

I am trying to obtain this using the HttpServletRequest and I know I have to call a procedure like the one below from inside the web service named "getDocument" But how do I initialise the HttpServletRequest inside getDocument?  That is how do I create the parameter "request" in the getDocument web service and initialise it to the request information?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     ...
     StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the client information so, for example:

```
@WebService()
public class SomeWebService {
    ...
    @Resource private WebServiceContext wsc;
    ...
    @WebMethod 
    public void methodOfWebService() {      
        MessageContext mc = wsc.getMessageContext();

        // retrieve the client information
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = 
            (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);    
        System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getContextPath());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to work when I make the call through SoapUI.  I have yet to test it on the web interface but confident it will work.  Will keep you updated